# How can I 100% prevent topics from being automatically created?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm very new to Apache Kafka. One of the things I am exploring is controlling the creation of topics on the server. Basically, I want to see if there is a way so that the server admins can 100% control which topics exist, preventing any application connecting to the server from creating any topics.

I'm testing this with some simple Java/Spring Boot proof-of-concept apps I've put together.

I have set `auto.create.topics.enable=false` on my Kafka server. This successfully prevents a Kafka producer from creating a topic, i.e., `KafkaTemplate.send()` will fail because the topic does not exist.

The problem is that consumers seem to still be able to create topics. When I start my consumer proof-of-concept app, the topics it is listening to are all automatically created on the server.

Now, there are settings I can configure in my Spring Boot application that prevent this. However, my goal is to enforce this rule from the Kafka server side, rather than relying on individual applications to enforce it.

I will add that I have not setup authentication or ACLs yet, I'm still somewhat early in my Kafka journey. So if this is something that would be handled by auth/ACL, that is great.

I figure there has to be some kind of solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that consumers seem to still be able to create topics

Configure the consumer, not just the broker

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_allow.auto.create.topics

Otherwise, if you're using Spring Kafka (not Spring Boot), then `@Bean NewTopic` methods are using the `AdminClient` and will themselves [create topics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/configuring-topics.html), not the consumers. When you do use Spring Boot, then an admin client is automatically configured from `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` value.

> if this is something that would be handled by auth/ACL, that is great.

It could help. Otherwise, any misconfigured, unauthorized client can still create topics, as a consumer, or just a random `kafka-topics.sh` command (or other tool) from anyone that has access to the cluster